# Shortening currency numbers using abbreviations while keeping currency format

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, currency, nsnumberformatter

1. I would like to shorten currency numbers by using "K" to represent thousands, "M" to represent millions and so forth.
2. Since the numbers represent currency value, I am also using `NSNumberFormatter` to properly format each number according to its value, currency, and the region setting of the device.

I have been able to do 1 and 2 separately, but am having a hard time doing both together.  At first I tried simply appending the abbreviations to the properly formatted output string from `NSNumberFormatter` (ex. appending "K" to "$10.3" to get "$10.3K").

This worked for most currencies, until I encountered region formats that show the currency symbol *after* the number value (ex. "+10.3 $US" would become "+10.3 $USK" rather than "+10.3K $US").

I'm not sure there is an easy way to determine whether the currency symbol comes before or after the number value for a given currency and region setting.  Any suggestions on a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am unaware of any API, but you can convert it into string and then you can extract characters and check...isn't is simple?

Comment: Be aware that some cultures also comma instead of point eg: 10,2K

Answer (score 4):

Interesting problem! The iOS library doesn't supports this (and I've never seen this sort of format supported in locale definitions on other platforms either) so you are stuck with doing your own implementation.

The convention of using the letter K and M itself might well not work in other locales. For example M is confusing for French speakers as both "mille", "million" and "milliard" (the French words for thousand, million and billion) start with the letter M and I have only ever seen **K** commonly used in French when used with money amounts (I'm a native speaker), with both lowercase **m** and uppercase **M** used in some fields such as geography to signify million and billion, respectively.

Perhaps you should weigh whether this is a must have in all locales or if there could be some other way to present your information. You could always do an implementation that abbreviates for locales where you know it works (such as en_US) and use non-abbreviated numbers for other locales.

Another suggestion is to base this on the active language and not use the iOS region format (i.e. decide the placement of the currency, the number and the letter K yourself through a format string in your `localizable.strings` file, so that translators can change it if necessary in each of your language). You'll still get the locale-dependent decimal point but everything else will be decided by your localization. It's not such a bad idea as users can actually get quite confused when they use the app in another language but are seeing numbers formatted in their own language (typically, if you understand English, you also understand the English number format, even if your native language uses a comma instead of a period as decimal separator--I know this intimately as I often get questions by confused users for my own app who try typing numbers with a period even though their locale expects a comma).

Comment: I ended up checking for the last digit in the string and inserting the abbreviation on my own, but I think this answer is really insightful.  I understand that "K" and "M" could be confusing to users of certain regions, but decided to go ahead for the following reasons: 1) Mainstream apps, namely Twitter, use "K" and "M" for all regions 2) The number is input by the user, and so hopefully a little less confusing when it is displayed 3) I cannot afford the space to show non-abbreviated numbers.

Comment: I plan to update my app to support various languages, otherwise I think basing the format on region rather than language is a good idea.  Regardless, I really appreciate the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ABNumberFormatter : NSNumberFormatter
@end


@implementation ABNumberFormatter

-(NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(id)obj
{
    static NSArray *names;
    if (!names) names = @[@" Bin", @" Milyon", @" Milyar", @" Trilyon"];
    double value = ((NSNumber*)obj).doubleValue;
    for (NSUInteger expo = 4; expo > 0; --expo)
    {
        double number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1 exponent:expo*3 isNegative:NO].doubleValue;
        if (value >= number)
        {
            self.positiveSuffix = names[expo];
            return [super stringForObjectValue:@(value / number)];
        }
    }
    return [super stringForObjectValue:obj];
}
@end
```

names are Turkish.